# Polymer 2.0 dom-repeat passing parameters

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x, dom-repeat

Quite new to Polymer so this is hopefully a simple question, but why do I have an output inside the slot "handle" and not one for the parameter has-arrow? Works fine when I just write the value in, as I do with position and expand-on, but I want them all to be dynamic from my Polymer.Element. Any thoughts?

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{headers}}" as="header">
    <th scope="col">
        <juicy-popover expand-on="click" position="beforetop center" has-arrow="[[header.hasArrow]]"> <!-- Nothing here -->
            <div slot="expandable">
                [[header.tooltip]]
            </div>
            <div slot="handle">
                [[header.title]]<br>
                [[header.hasArrow]] <!-- Displays here! -->
            </div>
        </juicy-popover>
    </th>
</template>
```

Script

```
class PolymerTable extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'polymer-table'; }
  static get properties() {
    return {
      headers: {
        type: Array,
        value() {
          return [
            {},
            {
                tooltip: 'Displays headers',
                title: 'Headers',
                position: 'beforetop center, beforetop left',
                expandOn: 'hover',
                hasArrow: 'true'
            },
            {
                tooltip: 'If this option is on, user can use regular expressions in route URI',
                title: 'Use regular expression',
                position: 'beforetop center',
                expandOn: 'hover',
                hasArrow: 'false'
            },
            {
                tooltip: 'If this option is on, surface nesting is allowed',
                title: 'Allow surface nesting',
                position: 'beforetop center',
                expandOn: 'hover',
                hasArrow: 'true'
            },
            {
                tooltip: 'If this option is on, this row is enabled',
                title: 'Enabled',
                position: 'beforetop center, beforetop beforeright',
                expandOn: 'hover',
                hasArrow: 'true'
            }
          ];
        },
        notify: true
      }
    };
  }
}
```

## UPDATE

It has nothing to do with calling a function or reading a property. It's simply about outputting a variable into a parameter.

I tried putting this before the juicy-popover.

```
<div test="{{index}}" testing="testing"></div>
```

Which gives the result:

```
<div testing="testing" class="style-scope polymer-table"></div>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, but inside `juicy-popover` your property would be just `hasArrow`, since you're passing that value directly, not a header object with an property called `hasArrow`

Comment: I tried this, but with the same result as my code. Please check my edit. It is a header object with a property.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `has-arrow=[[header.hasArrow]]`, you should call a class method and pass in the `index` of the `dom-repeat`, such as `has-arrow=[[_hasArrow(index)]]`

```
_hasArrow(index) {
  return this.headers[index].hasArrow;
}
```

**CAUTION:** The value won't be correct if you filter or sort the items in `dom-repeat`. They need to match the order of the property `headers`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. has-arrow="test" results in the same output, while has-arrow=[[_hasArrow(index)]], and my previous solution results in nothing. Not has-arrow="". Nothing. The property is not there.

The functions I did was this:
`_hasArrow(index) {
      console.log(this.headers[index].hasArrow);
   return this.headers[index].hasArrow;
  }`

Comment: the console.log returns the correct value, so it's no problem there. It's some kind of issue with printing it to the dom.

Comment: Could `index` be passed in as a string? Maybe it has to be coerced with `this.headers[+index].hasArrow`? I know `index` can be passed into a function because I did it in this example: https://codepen.io/johnthad/pen/dmGPww (but there it's used as a string).

Comment: No, `index` is passed as a number--`index === +index` is `true`. Sorry, I'm out of ideas at the moment.

Comment: This is really strange. It works on the `expand-on` property with `expand-on="[[_expandOn(index)]]"` using your logic, but somehow not on position and has-arrow.